# Jest doesn't recognize require syntax to import local images with Parcel

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, parcel

I have `<img src={require("../images/no-user-image.gif")} alt="" />` in one of my React components and it completely breaks my jest test.

I am using Parcel so this is why I am using `require` syntax.

Any ideas how to fix this?

This import syntax for Parcel 2 that I have found online doesn't work `import image from 'url:../images/no-user-image.png';` even when I changed the image to `png`. It says `Unable to resolve path to module`

When I use `import image from "../images/no-user-image.png";` this syntax which works if I set up `.parcelrc` file I am still getting Jest encountered an unexpected token error.

Details ->  `({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){�PNG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with image and audio files while using parcel 2.x. (It seems to work fine with CRA and the default web-pack setup.) But with parcel jest doesn't seem to know what to do with static files unless we tell it.

[Handling Static Assets](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets) info from the docs is helpful.

Here is what worked for me:

```
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
    'jest-transform-stub',
  },
  ...
};
```

[jest-transform-stub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transform-stub) is required `npm install --save-dev jest-transform-stub`